# python : get random value not exist in list

Tags: python, algorithm, random

I have a the following code:

```
def random_generate(list)
    x = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'
    x = list(x)
    random = choice(x)+choice(x)+choice(x)
```

Where `list` is a list of 3 characters string, e.g. `["abc","acd","aza"]`, and I call my function like:

```
random_generate(["abc", "acd", "aza"])
```

I want to generate a 3 characters string `random`, using characters from `x`, but which is not in `list`, e.g. `"aef"`.

I know I can make a loop until I get a string that is not in `list`, but it is not very efficient. Could someone provide me some hint on how to generate a string not in `list`?

Comment: ... What? Can you try explaining you question a bit better? What do you want?

Comment: I too don't understand what you mean, please try to clarify.

Comment: thanks for the feed back, i updated the question, please inform me if it is still not clear

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Where does the "forbidden list" come from? How many items is it expected to contain? If you want random 3-char base64 strings there are better ways to generate those. If you're using this to generate passwords or something this is horrific.

Comment: the forbidden list the the previous generated random values as every action i generate new random and store it at the db, i need it to be unique . it could include 10000 value at the list , it is not a password just value

Comment: One optimization would be to use a set to store the strings already used, how big is your sample space as opposed to the amount of unique strings you will have to generate? You could depending on the size generate all the combinations once and pick a random subelement each time persisting the data and removing each used subelement, `data = itertools.combinations_with_replacement('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/',3)`

Comment: also... use sets. `x in list` is O(n), `x in set` is O(1), much faster.

Comment: and... i know it sounds like a list is not very efficient, but there are 64*64*64 = ~32768 possible choices for the string. if they pass in 3 choices not to hit, you have a 3/32768 = ~0.001% chance of hitting it. most of the time, you're going to use your first choice, so there's (probably?) not much point in optimizing for the 'retry' case unless you expect the input list to be very large. And <irrelevancy redacted... thanks @Padraic!>

Comment: @CorleyBrigman, sample will not give you repeated characters

Comment: ahh, that is true...

Comment: I was going to suggest the same but `"aza"` is in the input list so sampling with replacement seems to be what the OP needs.

Comment: this cannot run. you are shadowing `list` with something that could be anything (and is not Callable).

Answer (score 3):

You could use a set to store the samples already taken:

```
def random_generate(lst):
    x = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'
    st = set(lst)
    samp = choice(x)+choice(x)+choice(x)
    while samp in st:
        samp = choice(x)+choice(x)+choice(x)
    return samp
```

Or generate all length 3 substrings once and pick a random substring each time you run the code, removing the picked subsequences  and persisting the data if the actual sample size if much larger, if it is just 64 choose 3 with replacement then persisting would take longer than simply creating the data set each time and using set.difference to get values not already taken:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

data =  combinations_with_replacement('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/',3)
```

It takes `3.09 ms` on my notebook to generate a list of all possible three character subsequences.

On a side note don't use `list` as a variable name, as it stands in your own code `list(x)` would error as you have shadowed the builtin `list`

Creating a list with close to 10k random substrings using the function generates a unique substring pretty efficiently:

```
In [18]:  x = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/' 
In [19]: l = [choice(x)+choice(x)+choice(x) for _ in range(10000)]

In [20]: len(set(l))
Out[20]: 9863

In [21]: timeit random_generate(l)
1000 loops, best of 3: 432 µs per loop
```

Even the worst case of  generating a set of all the combinations first and getting a random value from the difference of the sets takes milliseconds:

```
def random_generate_comb(lst):
    x = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'
    data =  set(combinations_with_replacement(x,3))
    return "".join(choice(list(data.difference(lst))))

In [23]: timeit random_generate_comb(l)
100 loops, best of 3: 15.2 ms per loop
```

So unless your sample size is way bigger than you have shown either approach should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your function:

```
import random
from string import ascii_letters,digits

def random_generate(in_list):
    x = ascii_letters + digits + '+/'
    random_ = ''.join(list((random.choice(x) for num in range(3))))
    while random_ in in_list:
        random_ = ''.join(list((random.choice(x) for num in range(3))))
    print(random_)
```

Function guarantees return string different from items in in_list